# What is the meaing of ({}) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the meaning of ({}) in react?
I see it used sometimes like:

`export const Story = ({story}) => {}`

I am guessing we are passing a story object?

Comment: Destructuring object. This is javascript and not only particular to React js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [**object destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Well, it's not `React`, **it's just vanilla `Javascript`**, which React (and a lot of other frameworks) are based on. You can spend some time to read the official document entirely or partially to grasp it thoroughly, it might benefit you in the long run.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
// instead of
export const Story = (props) => {
  const { story } = this.props
  return (
    <div>{story}</div>
  )
}
// or
export const Story = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.story}</div>
  )
}
//it'll be
export const Story = ({ story }) => {
  return (
    <div>{story}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called object destructuring

Both of these are equivalent

```
export const Story = (props) => {
  const { story } = props; 
  return (
    <div>{story}</div>
  )
}
```

You can destructure your object in your function parameters as well.

```
export const Story = ({ story }) => {
  return (
    <div>{story}</div>
  )
}
```